# Bypass Anti-ClickJack in C# WebBrowser Control?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

In my application I need to invoke a click to a certain button in a webBrowser (httprequests could not suffice in this situation) and I am unable to invoke any clicks to the button. After further digging, I found that the site has this piece of code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if (self === top) {
       var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
       antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
    } else {
       top.location = self.location;
    }
    </script>
```

I was wondering if it is possible to bypass the anticlickjack so that the button can be pressed as normal.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this code directly in the the html or referenced file?

Comment: The code is directly in the HTML of the site I believe.